# How can I change the default grep call (grepprg) to exclude directories?

Tags: neovim, ex-command

I am trying to change the default grep call to avoid unnecessary plugin installation. What I want from vim is to call the external search using the builtin command :grep with custom arguments, this is what I've tried putting in my rc:

```
set wildignore=*.o,*.obj,*~,*.pyc,.git/**,tags,cscope*
let &grepprg='grep -n -R --exclude=' . &wildignore . ' $*'
```

usage:

```
:set verbose grepprg
verbose=0                                                                
grepprg=grep -n -R --exclude=*.o,*.obj,*~,*.pyc,.git/**,tags,cscope* $*
:lgrep "_cast" ./src/*
```

output:

```
:!grep -n -R --exclude=*.o,*.obj,*~,*.pyc,.git/**,tags,cscope* "_cast" ./src/* 2>&1| tee /tmp/nvimzj3oo1/225                                                           zsh:1: no matches found: --exclude=*.o,*.obj,*~,*.pyc,.git/**,tags,cscope*
```

if I execute what vim tried:

```
$ grep -n -R --exclude=*.o,*.obj,*~,*.pyc,.git/**,tags,cscope* "_cast" ./src/* 2>&1| tee /tmp/nvimzj3oo1/225
./src/daemon/lim_l3_server_mw.cc:160:    LimL3Server *self = static_cast<LimL3Server *>(st);
```

so, I'm falling to see the problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If any of the [globs has no match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131032/globbing-fails-in-zsh-but-works-in-bash), in zsh, the command will be aborted. This means you need to [escape your globs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/use-grep-exclude-include-syntax-to-not-grep-through-certain-files).

I suggest you use `shellescape()` to build your `'grepprg'` command.

```
let &grepprg='grep -n -R --exclude=' . shellescape(&wildignore) . ' $*'
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'grepprg'
:h shellescape()
man zshexpn
```

### Alternatives to `grep`

Have you thought about using a different program for `'grepprg'` like [ag, the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), `git grep`, [ack](https://beyondgrep.com/), or [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)?

#### Ag, The Silver Searcher

Ag by default ignores the following files:

- Ignores binary files e.g. `*.o` and `*.pyc`
- Ignores version control directories e.g. `.git`, `.hg`, and `.svn`
- Will ignore files that matched your `.gitignore` files. I imagine your `tags` and cscope file will be ignored by this
- Uses PRCE regular expressions

This completely or nearly completely eliminates your excludes.

```
set grepprg=ag\ --vimgrep\ $*
set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m
```

If vanilla grep settings aren't your thing then you can use [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) which works with ag despite its name.

#### Using Ripgrep:

[Ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) is similar to Ag, the silver searcher.

- Ignores binary files e.g. `*.o` and `*.pyc`
- Ignores version control directories e.g. `.git`, `.hg`, and `.svn`
- Will ignore files that matched your `.gitignore` files. I imagine your `tags` and cscope file will be ignored by this
- Uses Rust's regular expressions
- Super fast! [Ripgrep is faster than {grep, ag, git grep, ucg, pt, sift}](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/)

Setting for you `vimrc`:

```
set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep
set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m
```

#### Using `git grep` or `:Ggrep`

If you are using `git` and [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Ggrep` which uses `git grep`. `git grep` can be a wonderful option because it will by default only search inside of tracked files. Therefore sidestepping the need to add ignores.

Using `git grep` without fugitive.vim:

```
set grepprg=git\ --no-pager\ grep\ --no-color\ -n\ $*
set grepformat=%f:%l:%m,%m\ %f\ match%ts,%f
```

Note: this uses the current working directory as a starting point

#### Using ack

[Ack](https://beyondgrep.com/) is a tool like grep, optimized for programmers. Ack is a perl script that can be easier to install on locked down system. It is the forerunner to both Ag and Ripgrep.

- Ignore version control directories by default
- Ignore backup files and core dumps by default
- Can use `ackrc` file to ignore more files by default
- Ack 1.* series ignores binary files by default. 2.* does not.
- Uses Perl's regular expressions
- Often faster than normal grep because it searches less files by default

`:grep` settings:

```
set grepprg=ack\ -s\ -H\ --nopager\ --nocolor\ --nogroup\ --column
set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m,%f:%l:%m
```

If vanilla grep settings aren't your thing then you can use [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim).

Comment: thanks for you answer. I'm don't like to use a external plugin if I have the grep right at my finger tips. lgrep is really  great. I found a strange behavior tought, if I don't feed the directories arguments it ignores my exclude pattern, again, I can't reproduce copying and paste on zsh.

Comment: Thank you for documenting many possible solutions. This answer is extremely helpful and well researched. Can you please explain where the different `grepformat` option values come from? I recently ran into problems with `,%f` in the `grepformat` string associated with `git grep`.

Comment: `'grepformat'` uses the same format as `'errorformat'`. See `:h errorformat` for more details. The `,%f` is a fallback which will recognize filenames in the case the format doesn't match `f:%l:%m` or `%m\ %f\ match%ts` beforehand. It is likely the first format will be the one used `%f:%l:%m`.

Comment: [vim-ripgrep](https://github.com/jremmen/vim-ripgrep) is a plugin for ripgrep.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my answer adopted from other answers (works and tested on macOSX):

```
" Grep {{{
" This is only availale in the quickfix window, owing to the filetype
" restriction on the autocmd (see below).
function! <SID>OpenQuickfix(new_split_cmd)
  " 1. the current line is the result idx as we are in the quickfix
  let l:qf_idx = line('.')
  " 2. jump to the previous window
  wincmd p
  " 3. switch to a new split (the new_split_cmd will be 'vnew' or 'split')
  execute a:new_split_cmd
  " 4. open the 'current' item of the quickfix list in the newly created buffer
  "    (the current means, the one focused before switching to the new buffer)
  execute l:qf_idx . 'cc'
endfunction

augroup grep_augroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* copen
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost l*    lopen
    autocmd FileType qf nnoremap <buffer> <C-v> :call <SID>OpenQuickfix("vnew")<CR>
    autocmd FileType qf nnoremap <buffer> <C-x> :call <SID>OpenQuickfix("split")<CR>
augroup END

" Set grepprg as RipGrep or ag (the_silver_searcher), fallback to grep
if executable("rg")
    set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep\ --no-heading\ --smart-case
    set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m,%f:%l:%m
elseif executable("ag")
    set grepprg=ag\ --vimgrep\ $*
    set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m
else
    let &grepprg='grep -n -r --exclude=' . shellescape(&wildignore) . ' $* .'
endif

function s:RipGrepCWORD(bang, ...) abort
  let search_word = a:1
  if search_word == ""
    let search_word = expand("<cword>")
  endif
  echom "Searching for " . search_word
  " Silent removes the "press enter to continue" prompt, and band (!) is for
  " not jumping to the first result
  execute "silent grep" . a:bang ." " . search_word
endfunction
command! -bang -nargs=? RipGrepCWORD call <SID>RipGrepCWORD("<bang>", "<args>")
nnoremap <c-f> :RipGrepCWORD!<Space>
" }}}
```

It includes:

**Command:**

`:RipGrepCWORD[!]` - Search for word, if string specified, search for it, if blank, search for word under cursor. Opens a quickfix list, removing the bang (!) will open the first result automatically.

**Mappings:**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> - populates EX-command with `:RipGrepCWORD!`

On the quickfix:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> - Opens result in a vsplit window

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> - Opens result in a split window

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really use the proposed solution because `shellescape` returns a string with simple quotes `'` so I couldn't use it inside the `--exclude` grep opt.

This is what I worked:

```
let &grepprg="grep -n -r --exclude=\\*.{o,obj,~,pyc,git}\\* --exclude={tags,cscope}\\* $* /dev/null"
```