# don't capture stderr for git grep as grepprg

Tags: external-command, git

I'm trying to use `git grep` as my `grepprg`, but I keep getting spurious files such as `~/fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. Is there a way to configure vim to correctly ignore diagnostic messages? I'm okay with general solutions for configuring `grepprg` and related options or solutions specific to `git grep`. However, I'd prefer a vim-only solution that doesn't involve writing wrapper programs around `git grep`.

Here's a snippet from my `:browse oldfiles` showing the spurious file.

```
1: ~/.vimrc.bak                                               
2: ~/.vimrc
3: ~/.bash_aliases
4: ~/.bashrc
5: /tmp/eee
6: /tmp/.vimrc
7: /tmp/.vimr
8: ~/fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

This problem is reproducible using the following vimrc.

```
set grepprg=git\ --no-pager\ grep\ --no-color\ -n\ $*
set grepformat=%f:%l:%m,%m\ %f\ match%ts,%f
```

The above vimrc is based on [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8858).

The first thing I tried is `set shellredir=>`, but the behavior of the grep `builtin` command does not appear to change according to the value of `shellredir`.

I've confirmed experimentally that `shellredir` has no effect on the `grep` command. I can confirm that `set shellredir="00000000"` doesn't appear to affect the `grep` ex command.

[The command `ex_make`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/92ea26b925a0835badb0af2d5887238a4198cabb/src/quickfix.c#L4765)  is used for `grep`, `make`, and other commands that populate the `quickfix` list. Briefly looking at the code, though, I can't tell why stderr is always captured on Linux and also can't say definitively that `shellredir` isn't used at all.

---

One semi-solution that does work is using a wrapper around git grep that immediately discards stderr before `vim` can see it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# ~/bin/gitgrep

open(STDERR, ">/dev/null");
exec("git", "--no-pager", "grep", "--no-color", "-n", @ARGV);
```

and the corresponding vimrc

```
set grepprg=$HOME/bin/gitgrep\ $*
set grepformat=%f:%l:%m,%m\ %f\ match%ts,%f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `git-grep` as `grepprg`, and here's why:

1. I mostly use `:vimgrep /pattern/ ##` to search my argument list.
2. I mostly use `ack` to search at the command line, though `git-grep` is helpful. Combined with `:Ack`, I'm set.
3. This function makes it easy to pop open vim with the quickfix ready to go:

```
vq () { 
    if (($# > 0)); then
        vim -q <("$@" 2>&1)
    else
        printf '%s\n' 'Usage: vq cmd' '' 'Use {cmd} output as quickfix list'
    fi
}
```

4. The script in `"$(git --exec-path)"/../../share/git-core/contrib/git-jump` makes this even easier: `git jump grep foo` opens up my editor similarly to how `vq` above functions. It also has other neat functions.
5. `git-grep` doesn't work well in non-git repos, as you've noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing the option consisting only of `%f` by itself. I'm not sure what `%m %f match%ts` means, since the original answer lacks explicit rationale for how the various `grepformat` strings were determined. I suspect it's related to `git grep`'s output for binary file matches.

The presence of `,%f` in the format string above means that, by default, any string that doesn't fit one of the other patterns will be interpreted as a filename.

Using the following lines to configure your `.vimrc` with `git grep` as the `grepprg` appears to solve the immediate problem.

```
let &grepprg="git --no-pager grep --no-color -n $*"                                                                                  
let &grepformat="%f:%l:%m,%m %f match%ts"
```

Note: I'm using `let &grepprg=...` instead of `set grepprg=...` because I think it makes it more obvious "where" the magic is.

`grepprg` and `grepformat` are just strings, but in the former `$*` (among other things) is handled specially and in the latter `,` (among other things) is handled specially.